# Is this summation$O(n^2)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think my summation is in $O(n^2)$ but I am not sure how to show it. How should I show that this summation $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n(j-i)$$ is in $O(n^2)$?

Comment: The result of the sum is zero.

Comment: @Mark, that inner sum starts at $j=i$, not $j=1$.

Comment: I'm sorry! I had read 1 instead of j.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The summation counts the number of triples of integers $(i,j,k)$ satisfying $1 \le i < k < j+1 \le n+1$. (Fix $i,j$ and see that there are $j-i$ values of $k$ that can fit in between). So you should get $\binom{n+1}{3}$.

Answer (score 4):

we know

1. $\sum_{i=b}^{n}{a}=(n-b+1)a$ (a and b are constant)
2. $\sum_{i=a}^ni=\frac{(n-a+1)(n+a)}{2}$ (a is constant)

so
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n(j-i)=\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=i}^n(j-i))=\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=i}^nj-\sum_{j=i}^ni))$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=i}^nj-(n-i+1)i)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=i}^nj-(ni-i^2+i))$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{(n-i+1)(n+i)}{2}-ni+i^2-i)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{n^2-i^2+n+i}{2}-ni+i^2-i)$$
$$=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n[(n^2+n)+i(-1-2n)+i^2]$$
$$=\frac12[n(n^2+n)+(-1-2n)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1)]$$
$$=\frac{n^3-n}{6}$$

so it's in $O(n^3)$

Comment: That inner sum starts at $j=i$, not $j=1$, and $\sum_{j=i}^nj\ne n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: yeah I got that I've correct that

Answer (score 2):

The sum is not zero, since all the numbers are non-negative, and some of them strictly positive. But you can sum it explicitly. Hint: you can do it using the formulas $$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac12n(n+1) \\ \sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1)$$ and the fact $\sum$ is linear.

Comment: So to answer the actual question: **NO**

Comment: @JeffE: Right! I wrote this answer in a bit of a hurry, so I forgot to mention that. Thanks for the comment.